# UITableView freezes when scrolling to bottom and adding new rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I scroll to the bottom of the UITableView the app is suppose to call a function ("CallAlamo(url: nextSearchURL)"), which just appends new content to array, then call tableView.reloadData(), and the tableview is then updated with the more content. However, the tableView freezes completely for about 2-3 seconds during this process. How can I get it to not freeze and work like most table views do in other apps where the new content is being loaded and the user is free to move the tableview.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let lastElement = posts.count - 1
    if indexPath.row == lastElement {

        callAlamo(url: nextSearchURL) //appends new content to array
        tableView.reloadData()

    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

This is what callAlamo does:

```
func callAlamo(url : String){
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
    response in

        self.parseData(JSONData: response.data!)

    })
}

func parseData(JSONData : Data){

    do{
        var readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .mutableContainers) as! JSONStandard
        //print(readableJSON)
        if let tracks = readableJSON["tracks"] as? JSONStandard{
            nextSearchURL = tracks["next"] as! String
            if let items = tracks["items"] as? [JSONStandard]{
                //print(items) //Prints the JSON information from Spotify
                for i in 0..<items.count{
                    let item = items[i]
                    let name = item["name"] as! String
                    let previewURL = item["preview_url"] as! String
                    if let album = item["album"] as? JSONStandard{
                        if let images = album["images"] as? [JSONStandard],let artist = album["artists"] as? [JSONStandard]{
                            let imageData = images[0] //this changes the quality of the album image (0,1,2)
                            let mainImageURL = URL(string: imageData["url"] as! String)
                            let mainImageData = NSData(contentsOf: mainImageURL!)

                            let mainImage = UIImage(data: mainImageData as! Data)

                            let artistNames = artist[0]
                            let artistName = artistNames["name"] as! String

                            posts.append(post.init(mainImage: mainImage, name: name, artistName: artistName, previewURL: previewURL))
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch{
        print(error)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Using @Anbu.Karthik choice 2:

Question 1: is "imageData" going to be my "mainImagedata"?

Question 2: I get an error in the Alamofire.request... saying "Extra argument 'method' in call" and when i delete it, i get an error that says "NSData? has no subscript members"

Comment: no need of this `tableView.reloadData()`  can you show the code of `callAlamo(u`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik okay just updated it. I know I also call tableView.reloadData() in callAlamo. However, I took out tableView.reloadData() in the tableView func and it still freezes

Comment: ya surely it takes , bz you are using `let mainImageURL = URL(string: imageData["url"] as! String)
                            let mainImageData = NSData(contentsOf: mainImageURL!)` , it will affect main thread,

Comment: directly pass the string to array and retrieve the array to image in cellforRowAt,

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Interesting. Im new to this. Could you answer the question with some code?

Comment: I update my answer, you need to customize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very bad code design, you should pass the url to the cell and let it do the fetching and parsing, and you are doing this on the main queue. You can do this using(using another queue) `DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.userInitiated).async`. IDK if Alamofire calls your closure on the main queue, but it look like it does the request on it. And don't forget to get back on the main queue when you want do to UI using `DispatchQueue.main.async`

UPDATE: I hope that it was clear that reloadData(), kinda gives you an infinite loop, and you should call these outside the TableViewDataSource funcitons

UPDATE 2: I don't see it here, but you should use `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` and use in it `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell.....`

Comment: I see, I see. Thank you for the response! Im  a little confused about what you mean by passing the url to the cell and "let it doe the fetching and parsing". Would you mind giving some example code of how to do what you're saying?

Comment: You need to make a class for the cell

Comment: Here is the example(of course in the class of the cell ): https://imgur.com/a/dJcR7#sjUKOQ7

Comment: @OriginalAlchemist you should follow the iOS dev course from Stanford to really get a taste of good iOS code

Comment: I most definitely will check it out! Thank you!

Comment: I got it to work! Its super efficient! The only concern I have is when the user scrolls down and then scroll back up the table view cell image disappears for a second and then comeback. I know its because the cells are being reused. Is there anyway to fix this or make it not noticeable?

Comment: @OriginalAlchemist you can store images after you downloaded them